# How to find specific text with it's correspondence value from a text input using Regex and Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have some text input and I want to extract few information from the text.
For that, I am trying to use Regular Expression and am able to do that except for two fields- rent and transfer.

The input text is as below-

```
my_str = "19 Aug standing order rent Apolo Housing Assoc. 500.00 50.00
20 Aug transfer from John wick saving a/c 200.00 130.90"
```

Now I want to extract rent like- `rent 500.00` and transfer as `transfer 200.00` but somehow only 'rent' and 'transfer' keywords are extracting only.

Below is my code in Python for the same-

```
import re
find_rent = re.search(r"(rent)+([0-9,.]*)", my_str)
found = find_rent.group()
print(found)
```

With the above code, only 'rent' is extracted not 'rent 500.00'. Similar code I am using for transfer also.

Please guide me on what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
\b(transfer|rent)\D+(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y11hJG/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(transfer|rent)` - Group 1: a `transfer` or `rent` word
- `\D+` - one or more non-digits
- `(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*)` - Group 2: one or more digits, and then zero or more occurrences of a comma/period and one or more digits

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/UG0m7O):

```py
import re
s = '19 Aug standing order rent Apolo Housing Assoc. 500.00 50.00\n20 Aug transfer from John wick saving a/c 200.00 130.90'
rx = r'\b(transfer|rent)\D+(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*)'
for m in re.finditer(rx, s):
    print(f'{m.group(1)} {m.group(2)}')
```

Output:

```
rent 500.00
transfer 200.00
```

For a single term search, you can use

```py
import re
s = '19 Aug standing order rent Apolo Housing Assoc. 500.00 50.00\n20 Aug transfer from John wick saving a/c 200.00 130.90'
w = 'rent'
rx = fr'\b{w}\D+(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*)'
m = re.search(rx, s)
if m:
    print(f'{w} {m.group(1)}')
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/Ch5dcH).

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor. It really works for my text.

Comment: If I want to extract the values separately- one by one then what should I change here?

Comment: @Hitman I added the single term search at the end of the post. Also, if your `w` contains special chars, use `re.escape(w)`, not just `w`.

Comment: Wiktor, what if some text may contain text like 'Rent' or 'RENT'. IN that case what should be the changes?

Comment: @Hitman `rx = fr'(?i)\b{re.escape(w)}\D+(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*)'`. The `(?i)` inline modifier makes the pattern case insensitive.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. It answers my all doubts.